# Local site not running under MAMP after Yosemite upgrade

Tags: apache, mamp

I just upgraded to Yosemite and noticing problems with MAMP. I was running Piwik locally (port 7788) before the upgrade, and it worked perfectly. Now, however, when I start MAMP I just get a `500 Internal Server Error`.

Some searching around suggested that one issue was that MAMP was using Port 8888 for Apache and 8889 for MySQL, whereas they should now be changed to Port 80 and 3306 respectively (the default ones for those apps). This didn't change anything for me though.

I also read it could be an issue around PHP and a suggestion was to go to `\etc\apache2\httpd.conf` and uncomment the line `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`, again this did nothing. 
I don't know enough about Apache2/MySQL/PHP to trawl through them and figure anything out so I'm hoping someone here can suggest how I go about correcting this.

Answer (score 0):

MAMP will use it's own version of Apache2 so you will need to change the settings/ uncomment the modules in that httpd.conf file.

/etc/apache2/ is the default server preinstalled on the machine, which is different to MAMP's

Try looking for it here: Applications ▸ MAMP ▸ conf ▸ apache

Comment: Checking the conf file in that location I can see that it is already uncommented and reads `LoadModule php5_module        /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/modules/libphp5.so`

Comment: Ah ok, well I know a few people who had issues with it when they upgraded, think the conf file was corrupted. Can you try re installing it?